# Spawn a image on another image giving a coordinate

Tags: javascript, html, css, xhtml

I have some image coordinates and I want to use them to put a small image on those with javascript. Can this be accomplished with javascript or I need to create the div and modify it's css attributes? By the way: the image can be placed anywhere on the page.

Comment: with javascript you can create any dom element you need and also modify the styles

Comment: Yes, but how to change the style to place it on the exact coordinates of a not-fixed image?

Comment: you want to place the image wherever you want on the screen, that means you must put the position to absolute. Then you can define its position per `top`,`left`,`right`,`bottom`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fully working code: [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yChyj/2/)

**CSS**

```
.overlays{
    position:absolute;
}
```

**JS**

```
function showImage() {
    // myImage : ID of image on which to place new image

    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');

    console.log(image.width);

    margin = 20;

    l = image.offsetLeft;
    t = image.offsetTop;
    w = image.width;
    h = image.height;

    // Location inside the image
    offX = parseInt(Math.random() * w);
    offY = parseInt(Math.random() * h);

    if(offX > margin) offX -= margin;
    if(offY > margin) offY -= margin;

    l += offX;
    t += offY;

    var newImage = document.createElement("img");
    newImage.setAttribute('src', '1.jpg');
    newImage.setAttribute('class', 'overlays');
    newImage.style.left = l + "px";
    newImage.style.top = t + "px";
    document.body.appendChild(newImage);
}
```

Comment: Don't ever use the minus sign (`-`) in variable names! That's invalid JS (`SyntaxError: Unexpected token -`), not to mention making it harder to read.

Comment: How to calculate off-x and off-y in pure JS? (The position of the image is relative and can I say, random)

Comment: @Octavian Use rand() to geta random x,y.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to place the new image on coordinates `(X,Y)` of a parent image:

```
var newImg = document.getElementById('newImg'), // your new (small) image
    img = document.getElementById('parentImg'); // parent image
document.body.insertBefore(newImg, img); // Insert the new image before the image
document.body.insertBefore(img, newImg); // Then switch places (So the small image is after the big one in the DOM)

newImg.style.position = 'relative';
newImg.style.left = X + "px";
newImg.style.top = (Y - img.height)+"px"; // Substract the height of the source image to get the position relative to the top left.
```

The double `insertBefore` is to insert the new image after the bid one, by first inserting it before the big one, then moving the big one in front of it.
Then, it's just a matter of setting the new image's coordinates relative to the big image.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5rBP/3/)** (Set to display the overlay after 2 seconds to show the difference)

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
#yourId{
    position: absolute;
}
```

js:

```
var img = document.getElementById('yourId'), // or any other selector
    x = x, // your data
    y = y; // your data
img.style.left = x+"px";
img.style.top = y+"px";
```